# What does this for loop condition mean in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a problem with figuring out what the following loop means as i'm new to C.
I have some value of temp and an array v. Middle part evaluates to true or false, so i am really confused.

```
for( j=i ; j>0 && temp<v[j-1] ; j--){...}
```

Comment: Which part exactly is confusing to you? The "middle part" is always an expression that evaluates to true or false

Comment: What values does this for loop go through? It doesn't have a range it seems. It goes from j to true/false ?? for example for(j=0 ; j<5 ; j++) makes a lot of sence.

Comment: The first sets up the initial conditions, the second the part that must evaluate to true before each iteration or the loop will terminate, the final part is what happens after each loop and before the next.

Comment: It loops until either `j` reaches 0 or the value of `temp` is bigger or equal than `v[j-1]`, whichever happens first

Comment: `for` loops in C are pretty general: the one you know iterates from 0 to 4. But you can also decrement and count down from some value to 0. Or you can double (`j = j * 2`) or halve (`j = j / 2`) or ...

Comment: It's worth noting that `j>0 && temp<v[j-1]` does _short circuit evaluation_. This means that if we have `cond1_expr && cond2_expr`, if `cond1_expr` evaluates to _false_, then `cond2_expr` will _not_ be evaluated. _Without_ that, the sequence would be: evaluate `cond1_expr`, evaluate `cond2_expr`, logically AND them. This is relevant because without the short circuit, `v[j-1]` would be evaluated with a `j` of 0, which means `v[-1]` which might be undefined behavior. Likewise for logical OR: `A || B`. If `A` evaluates to true, `B` is _not_ evaluated.

Comment: In other words, short circuit evaluation of `if (A && B) do_something;` is like: `if (A) { if (B) do_something; }`

Answer (score 2):

This line is pretty simple:
 Iterate `'i'` elements of array `'v'` in backward direction while values are less than 'temp'.
 When value appear as more or equal than 'temp' or `'j'` went to zero then exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the body of the `for` loop while both conditions `j>0` and `temp<v[j-1]` are `true`.

**Here j=i,i-1,.......,2,1,0**

Answer (score 0):

1. Set initial value of `j` to `i`
2. Check `j` to see if it is greater than `0` and check `temp` to see if it is less than value of element in array `v` at index `j - 1`. If both cases are true, proceed to step 3; if either case is false, proceed to step 5.
3. Perform body of `for` loop. At end, decrement `j` by `1`
4. Repeat step 2
5. Exit Loop